# why isnt javascript working in f12 dev tools?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am accustomed to working with either chrome or FF but am currently working on a project that requires me to use ie10 set to ie8 standards in f12 developer tools.

I am finding that whatever I type in the console is not being processed by javascript but simply output exactly as I enter it.

For example if I type 1+2 I get back the string "1+2" not "3" as expected. If I type console.log('test'); it outputs "console.log('test')" and not "test" as expected.

The project uses frames and xsl, and the js only works in ie8, but there are no errors in the console when set to ie8 mode, so Im not sure why javascript entered into the console is not being parsed.

This is probably a noob question and there is something basic Im missing, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Internet Explorer.

Comment: sounds like you have a problem with your browser.

Comment: Actually it was a browser issue. I think I solved it. The browser was stuck on the "active x controls" alert popup.

Comment: Just an advise: If you need to support IE8 test it with the [free VM from Microsoft](http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads). And if you need to test it with Compatibility Mode in settings.

Comment: Have you tried IE11 using enterprise mode? The tools there are updated and might work, or at least we could better diagnose the issue.